# Which cfsqltype to use for Oracle's Number(*,0) datatype in cfqueryparam?

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle10g, coldfusion-10, cfqueryparam

I am a little bit confused with which datatype I should use for Oracle's `Number(*,0)` with zero scale and any precision?

Which one should I use `CF_SQL_INTEGER` or `CF_SQL_FLOAT`? and why?

Comment: I know that both `CF_SQL_INTEGER` and `CF_SQL_FLOAT` works, but honestly I never thought of the recommended of two to use for an orcle Number(*,0).

Comment: Wouldn't you just use CF_SQL_NUMERIC as its a numeric data type?

Comment: @haxtbh, Yes, I could use CF_SQL_NUMERIC. Recently, I have been shifted to a legacy application. They have explicitly used CF_SQL_INTEGER for Number(*,0) and CF_SQL_FLOAT for Number(*,positive integer). Now I am wondering why that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`Number(*,0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209) means you are working with very large integers, ie up to 38 digits and no decimal places:

> `column_name NUMBER (precision, scale)`
>
> ... **precision** (total number of digits) and **scale** (number of digits to
>   the right of the decimal point):
>
> `column_name NUMBER (*, scale)`
>
> In this case, the precision is 38, and the specified scale is
>   maintained.

That is too many digits to store in `CF_SQL_INTEGER`. To support the full range, requires a type with a much greater capacity. Looking at the standard [JDBC Mappings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/basic3.htm) that means either `java.sql.Types.NUMERIC` or `java.sql.Types.DECIMAL`. Both of those use java's [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for storage, which has more than enough capacity for `Number(38,0)`.

The [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html) matrix and [Oracle JDBC driver](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm) documentation both say the same thing about the DECIMAL type. Since `java.sql.Types.NUMERIC` is really just a synonym for `java.sql.Types.DECIMAL` you can use either one.

*Note: When using cfqueryparam, if you omit the "scale" attribute, it defaults to scale="0", ie no decimal places.*

```
    <cfqueryparam type="CF_SQL_DECIMAL" scale="0" value="....">
```

Comment: What if the we have datatype Number(*,0) for a table column but we are passing the values that are within the integer range?

Comment: (Edit) If the values will *always* fall within the 32 bit integer range, then you could use either NUMERIC/DECIMAL or INTEGER. However, if things ever change and you try and pass in a value that is bigger, cfqueryparam will throw an exception and the query won't run.  It does not really save much, so I tend to stick to whatever the underlying table/column type is, unless there is a very good reason not to.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up. I am working on a legacy app and it has CF_SQL_INTEGER and CF_SQL_FLOAT written everywhere for Number datatype. It will be really bad for us to change the cfsqltype to DECIMAL one but I will use it for new queries.

Comment: (Edit) Well `float` would only be necessary if you are working with decimal places. Though its use is actually discouraged in the JDBC API. (It was quite amusing reading about it when trying to figure out the [correct types for MySQL](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2010/01/cfqueryparam-matrix-for-mysql-5.html) a while back. Interestingly, the CF docs do not mention this). However, if precision is important, definitely use DECIMAL - not float or double. The latter two are *approximate* types which are not suitable for representing things like currency.

Comment: One other thing about types. It usually does not make a difference with numbers, but occasionally using a *different* cf_sql_type than the column it is being compared to can have a negative impact on the query plan. Normally databases are smart enough to coerce the single cfqueryparam value to the correct type if needed. However, once in a while it may force the database to cast all of the values in the *database column* to a different type, resulting in a less efficient query plan.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for taking time to answer and comment. If you ever create/ have a blog to share your knowledge, You let me know. I will definitely be the one of the regular reader of it.

Comment: Thanks. The one above was my blog .. once upon a time ;-) though no longer maintained. One of these days, I expect to get bitten by the writing bug again...